# Multi-select boxes not search with parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, frontend

i'm using select2 in v4.0.3

When I search through the children, for example, "sub category 1", the search appears and your parent "Category 1" is also located above.

https://ibb.co/iNAdLG

But, when I search for "Category 1" it does not show me any of the children. I have reviewed the documentation and several approaches but none has worked for me.

https://ibb.co/eVuSEb

Annex images of reference and code

```js
$("#multisearch").select2({
  language: "es",
  closeOnSelect: false,
  placeholder: "Comienza tu búsqueda",
  data: [{
      id: 0,
      text: 'Linea 1',
      children: [{
          id: 1,
          text: 'San Pablo'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          text: 'Pajaritos'

        },
        {
          id: 3,
          text: 'Las Rejas'
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          text: 'Ecuador'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      text: 'Linea 2',
      children: [{
          id: 6,
          text: 'La Cisterna'
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          text: 'El Parrón'

        },
        {
          id: 8,
          text: 'Lo Ovalle'
        },
        {
          id: 9,
          text: 'Ciudad del niño'
        },
        {
          id: 10,
          text: 'Pajaritos'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'prueba'
    },
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select multiple id="multisearch" style="width:500px">
</select>
```

I will be attentive, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by implementing custom matcher function.

Please check the example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

function customMatcher(params, data) {
        data.parentText = data.parentText || "";
        if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
            return data;
        }

        if (data.children && data.children.length > 0) {
            var match = $.extend(true, {}, data);
            for (var c = data.children.length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
                var child = data.children[c];
                child.parentText += data.parentText + " " + data.text;

                var matches = customMatcher(params, child);

                if (matches == null) {
                    match.children.splice(c, 1);
                }
            }

            if (match.children.length > 0) {
                return match;
            }

            return customMatcher(params, match);
        }

        var original = (data.parentText + ' ' + data.text).toUpperCase();
        var term = params.term.toUpperCase();

        if (original.indexOf(term) > -1) {
            return data;
        }

        return null;
    }
    
$("#multisearch").select2({
  language: "es",
  closeOnSelect: false,
  matcher: customMatcher,
  placeholder: "Comienza tu búsqueda",
  data: [{
      id: 0,
      text: 'Linea 1',
      children: [{
          id: 1,
          text: 'San Pablo'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          text: 'Pajaritos'

        },
        {
          id: 3,
          text: 'Las Rejas'
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          text: 'Ecuador'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      text: 'Linea 2',
      children: [{
          id: 6,
          text: 'La Cisterna'
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          text: 'El Parrón'

        },
        {
          id: 8,
          text: 'Lo Ovalle'
        },
        {
          id: 9,
          text: 'Ciudad del niño'
        },
        {
          id: 10,
          text: 'Pajaritos'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'prueba'
    },
  ]
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select multiple id="multisearch" style="width:500px">
</select>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much, I am going to read the code to study it and have it in the future.

I have another doubt, I think it's simpler, I'm trying to modify the language to Spanish (es) and as the documentation does not work for me, I saw that there are people who have the same error but it has not worked for me.